# Is there a "standard" "textbook" model for making re-financing decisions?

Tags: interest-rates, brownian-motion, models

You have a loan with an x% interest rate. Rates fall to y%. Should you pay a fee to refinance?

Presumably not if the NPV of the saved interest is less than the fee. However, if you always refinance whenever the NPV of saved interest is a mere 1¢ greater than the fee, interest rates could drop 10pp, and you'd end up making literal pennies, so a naive cost-benefit analysis is clearly useless.

So, as with the Black-Scholes model with options, and as with Markowitz/CAPM with stocks, is there a "standard" model for evaluating refinancing decisions? Maybe something like "assume mortgage rates follow a Brownian motion" model.

My Google-fu is epically failing me :(

Comment: If I understood correctly you are looking for decision rules for *optimal mortgage refinancing*. There are some papers on this, but I don't know which are considered the best, or whether there is an accepted standard. There is also research on how people actually refinance, which is a different issue (people don't do it optimally).

Answer (score 3):

Assume that the loan in question is a fixed-rate mortgage. There are some standard heuristics recommended by consumer finance specialists which can be quite far from the "textbook" model (also known as optimal mortgage refinancing, as pointed out by nbbo2). These include refinancing when prevailing rates are at least 0.50% (50bps) lower than your current mortgage rate (earlier rules suggested a trigger of 2% but the costs associated with mortgage refinancing have generally trended lower over time) or a **breakeven** method which compares the cost of refinancing with the monthly payment savings realized over the expected tenure in the house.

Another layer of sophistication could be added to this analysis by discounting cash flows and by including tax considerations (specifically, the tax treatment of discount points and closing costs).

Still, neither of the above approaches consider the value of the prepayment option that the borrower receives when they hold a mortgage. In particularly, these approaches ignore the trade-off between paying an above-market rate right now and the "time value" of the prepayment option -- it may be better to refinance in the future as opposed to now. The **optimal refinancing** rule would say that one should refinance when:

PV(after-tax monthly savings) = Refinancing costs + Loss in option value

There is a loss in the value of the prepayment option we receive when we exchange the old mortgage for a new lower rate one because the old one is in-the-money whereas the new one is either at-the-money or out-of-the-money.

Of course, as nbbo2 also points out, the regular consumer does not typically have the sophistication/knowledge to value this prepayment option which depends crucially on the term structure of interest rates.

For a down-to-earth analysis of this issue, see Chapter 2 in [A Financial Analysis of Consumer Mortgage Decisions](https://www.mba.org/docs/default-source/research---riha-reports/9322_research_mortgagemanual_paper.pdf?sfvrsn=c00998d5_1).